# How to trigger Raspberry Pi 3 to take action from Server

Tags: python, linux, triggers, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am currently developing a system where I need to send notification to Raspberry to run a Python file. It is much like a observer pattern design where my server is publisher and Raspberry is the observer. Worth to note that, I actually need to interact with one Raspberry at the time (even I have dozens of them). Specifically, on a specific event, I need to warn a single Raspberry that it has to take an action.

I searched for it literally for all the night but I could not find anything coming handy. Nothing really give me a clue how to implement this.

The most close answer I could find is [this technology firm's product called PubNub](http://pubnub.com/blog/2015-06-11-remote-control-raspberry-pi-leds-from-a-web-browser-ui/) which can actually work. However, as I need is a one-to-one interaction, this might be unnecessary because it is designed to publish a data to multiple clients.

Long story short, I need to trigger Raspberry to take some action in accordance to the some data coming from the server, whenever it receives the data.

Server is running on Amazon and implemented with Python 2.7.

Please do not hesitate to ask me for further detail, if I am missing any.

Thanks for all the supports,

---

**EDIT**

Just a recent update with an improvement to my answer. As far as I understand, sockets are able to manage this process. Such as from client (Raspberry in my case) listening for the server and server sending some data. Taken from [this site](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication), I managed to make a sample run on my computer, from my local. I used Port 5000 as their 'meeting point'.

Below is the code:

client.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket


TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5000
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = b"Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print("received data:", data)
```

server.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket


TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5000
BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connection address:', addr)
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print("received data:", data)
    conn.send(data)  # echo
conn.close()
```

However, I still have some questions.

Firstly, I want to learn whether the same thing work when I deploy the project and how. If that will work - lets say I have an url for the server like 'www.thisisanexampleurl.com' - simply assignign a port for it, will work?

Secondly, assuming first question is done, what is the way of making it continous so that it does not stop after receiving and sending data once. Because currently, when it makes the data transfer, it stops working.

Thanks again for the all support and again please do not hesitate to ask me for the further details i am missing any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something this simple:

Run something like this on your pi:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = ""
port = 12345
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    try:
        clientsock, addr = s.accept()
    except OSError:
        continue
    message = clientsock.recv(20)

    #the code you want to run
    print("doing %s" % message)

    clientsock.close()
```

And this on your server every time you want the pi to take action:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 12345
s.connect((host, port))
s.send("foo")
s.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask why the host names or empty or 0.0.0.0? I mean, how can it know which server it is connecting without the host names, do I miss something here?

Comment: @KutayDemireren the empty host name should mean it uses whatever adress is available, but yes, you should change the 0.0.0.0 for the ip adress of the pi if you're accessing it outside the network, in which case you'll of course also need to forward the port you use - and you might want to check if the string it received contains a password so not anyone can tell it to do something (at least afaik that might be an issue otherwise - I have little experience).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess that would a better solution and seems like it is working locally. I will see what happens when I deploy the project. Let me ask a final question about it, what if I create a meeting point for them, with my url (like, www.exampleurl.com) and with port 5000. In this case, they will both know where they should look at so I would not worry about what is the current address or the pi's ip address. Eventually, I will have like dozens of pi, so I want to avoid from using the ip address.

Comment: @KutayDemireren Sorry for long delay. If your pis will all be on the same ip address, I believe you will have to use a different port number for each one. If you only want to forward one port, you could probably have a pi on that port further connect to the other pis if the message it receives instructs it to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Pyro4](http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/).  It lets you avoid having to write network code at all and just write code that calls remote Python objects as if they were running on the same machine. In your case, the server could call a normal Python method on your Raspberry Pi to do something. It has many features but you can start with something extremely simple.

raspberry pi code:

```
import Pyro4

@Pyro4.expose
class Raspberry:
    def something(self, arg):
        print("called with:", arg)
        return "hi from pi"

Pyro4.Daemon.serveSimple({Raspberry: "raspberry"})
```

server code to make the pi do something:

```
import Pyro4
rasp = Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:raspberry")
print(rasp.something(42))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it looks really simple as you said! I think I can consider that one instead of the python's socket library. Still, one question on my mind tho: How can my raspberry is recognized, given your example? I mean, for example the name 'raspberry' can be given from another one also. How can it differentiate?

Comment: My specific example requires the use of the Pyro4 Name Server -- a registry that binds logical names (here: "raspberry") to network locations so that you don't have to worry about them yourself.  You can also skip this and directly connect to your raspberry pi but that requires you to type the hostname or ip address of the raspberry pi in the code for the server.

Comment: Additionally, to differentiate among multiple Pi's, you either have to choose a unique name for each of them (this can be automated ofcourse, by using a suffix or whatever), use Pyro4's metadata feature for yellow-pages lookup, or connect directly to their individual hostnames.  This is all explained in Pyro4's manual :)

Comment: Okay, yeah. I think I am getting there :) I already started the documentation of Pyro4, thanks for this advice. I really like how simply it can manage the process. However, can I ask a last question :)? I am just confused on this point in the case using name server. Lets say I called it 'raspberry' as its name server. Now, what is the difference between me and you calling the pi method with finding my pi from 'PYRONAME:raspberry'? I mean, there has to be something that is unique to me and my raspberry, right?

Comment: I am afraid I don't fully understand your question. Are you asking about other people accessing your Pi and calling that method?  That is not possible as long as the machines on your network are not accessible from the outside world. Also, the Pyro name server is something you will be running yourself somewhere (perhaps on another Pi) if you decide to use it -- it is not something that makes Pyro objects globally accessible for everyone, it is still fully under your control

Comment: Well, my server is running on Amazon. The point is that server has actually nothing to do with my pi. They are in separate networks, they are not connected at all. That is why I still cannot understand what is the difference here in the name server so that you cannot access but I can ? With you, I mean outside world of course

Comment: Oh, I thought you wrote that some event happens on the server (running on amazon I now understand) and that it then needed to signal to a Pi to do something?   Not the other way around?   It doesn't really matter though, just reverse the client and server code.    What does matter is security... where are your Pi's running?  If they're accessed from over the internet you better make sure they only get requests from machines you trust.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130865/discussion-between-kutay-demireren-and-irmen-de-jong).